# nodejs で erb のようなテンプレート処理が行いたい

Tags: node.js

ruby では、テンプレート処理を行うにあたっては、 erb を用いるのがデファクトです。

nodejs で、同じようにテンプレート処理を行いたくなったとき、これが可能なライブラリは、何が一般的でしょうか?(そのようなものはありますか?)

Answer (score 2):

Node.jsではEJSというものがあります。
http://www.embeddedjs.com/

`npm`コマンドでインストールできます。
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs

Answer (score 1):

テンプレート(レイアウト)の拡張という点でいえば、[Nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/)が容易です。
(EJSは、テンプレートの拡張が面倒だったと思います。)

以下のようにテンプレートを拡張できます。

#### layout.html

```
<body>
  <header class="main">header</header>
  <section class="content">
    <nav class="side_nave">navi</nav>
    <main>
       {% block main %}
       dummy
       {% endblock %}
    </main>
  </section>
</body>
```

#### index.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block main %}
This is the main contents
{% endblock %}
```

#### index.htmlのレンダー結果

```
<body>
  <header class="main">header</header>
  <section class="content">
    <nav class="side_nave">navi</nav>
    <main>
       This is the main contents
    </main>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

`nodejs`では、[pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html)、[handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) が比較的有名と思われますが、他にも沢山あってデファクトはないので、自分の好みで選択したらいいと思います。erbに構文が近いのは、EJSのようです。

また、最近人気急上昇中のフレームワーク [Vue.js](https://jp.vuejs.org/) がテンプレートとしても使え、Nuxt.js と使ってサーバーサイドのアプリケーションを作成したり、VuePress と使って静的サイトを作成することができます。新しいものが好きであれば使ってみると面白いと思います。